# Showing a var from a controller when pressing a button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am a newbie in laravel 4. When pressing a button I want to display a message on the screen.
This is my view:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>
            Management
        <div class="pull-right">
                    {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn btn-small btn-info iframe')) }}
                @if(isset($pressMe))
                    {{$pressMe }}
                @endif
            </div>
        </h3>
    </div>
@stop
```

My routes are defined like that:

```
Route::get('pressMe', 'TestController@getIndex');
Route::post('pressMe', 'TestController@postTest');
Route::controller('pressMe', 'TestController');
```

Finally this is my test controller:

```
<?php
class TestController extends BaseController {

/**
 * Inject the models.
 */
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct ();
}

public function getIndex() {

    // Show the page
    return View::make ( 'admin/pressMe/index' )->with('pressMe', '');;
}

/**
 * Start Test script.
 */
public function postTest() {
    $pressMe = 'It works!';

    return View::make ( 'admin/pressMe/index' )->with('pressMe', $pressMe);
}
}
```

However, when pressing the button nothing gets shown on the screen.

Any recommendations what I am doing wrong?

I really appreciate your answer!

UPDATE

In my filters file I have a protection against CSS, however, I now get the following error:

```
Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException thrown with message ""

Stacktrace:
#21 Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\app\filters.php:96
#20 {closure} in <#unknown>:0
#19 call_user_func_array in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php:199
#18 Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher:fire in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher.php:154
#17 Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher:until in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:1468
#16 Illuminate\Routing\Router:callRouteFilter in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:240
#15 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:callFilter in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:114
#14 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:before in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher.php:55
#13 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher:dispatch in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:962
#12 Illuminate\Routing\Router:Illuminate\Routing\{closure} in <#unknown>:0
#11 call_user_func_array in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php:109
#10 Illuminate\Routing\Route:run in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:1028
#9 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatchToRoute in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php:996
#8 Illuminate\Routing\Router:dispatch in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:775
#7 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:dispatch in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:745
#6 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\barryvdh\laravel-debugbar\src\Middleware\Stack.php:34
#5 Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\Stack:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\Middleware.php:72
#4 Illuminate\Session\Middleware:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Queue.php:47
#3 Illuminate\Cookie\Queue:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cookie\Guard.php:51
#2 Illuminate\Cookie\Guard:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\stack\builder\src\Stack\StackedHttpKernel.php:23
#1 Stack\StackedHttpKernel:handle in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php:641
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:run in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\lara\public\index.php:49
```

That´s my filter:

```
Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::getToken() != Input::get('csrf_token') &&  Session::getToken() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have lots of half completed codes in your snippet.

*view*:

you have a submit button yet you have no form in place. either use ajax, or javascript to submit the form or simpler, just write the form.

```
@section('content')
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>
            Management
        <div class="pull-right">
             <form method="post" action="/pressMe">
               <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-info iframe" value="Save" />
             </form>

             @if(Session::has('pressMe'))
               {{Session::get('pressMe')}}
             @endif 

            </div>
        </h3>
    </div>
@stop
```

remove the

```
 @if(isset($pressMe))
   {{$pressMe }}
 @endif
```

and add this instead,

```
@if(Session::has('pressMe'))
    {{Session::get('pressMe')}}
@endif
```

*Just like i did above in the view code snippet*

**In the route file:**

```
Route::get('pressMe', 'TestController@getIndex');
Route::post('pressMe', 'TestController@postTest');
```

remove `Route::controller('pressMe', 'TestController');`

Don't mix up manual routing and controller routing. It will give you headache later. Stick to one. Either Controller routing, or Manual Routing, or Restful routing. **don't mix!**

**In the Test Controller**:

```
public function postTest() {
    $pressMe = 'It works!';

    return Redirect::to('/pressMe')->with('pressMe', $pressMe);
}
```

.... *and you are done.*

## update #1

**view:**

```
<form method="post" action="{{URL::action('TestController@postTest')}}">
```

and

**TestController:**

```
return Redirect::action('TestController@postTest')->with('pressMe', $pressMe);
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! My problem is now still I get redirected to http://localhost/pressMe. However, I just would like to stay on the page `http://localhost/laravel_project/lara/public/admin/pressMe`. So basically the view I am redirected to is not found ;(. Any recommendations how I can print the message on the same view?

Comment: you have to use absolute url here. you can't use relative. check the update.

Comment: Thx a lot for your update. It still does not work yet. Please be so kind and look at my update.

Comment: this is a totally different problem and not related to above. you should open a new question with the error you are having.